# "Нарошка" — это что?

Tags: словообразование

*Понарошку* это почему или по чему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова "нарошка" в языке не фиксируется, так что образование "понарашку" можно считать окказиональным или по крайней мере не совсем обычным для подобных наречий.

Но у слова "нарочно" (старомосковское произношение "наро**ш**но") есть фиксируемое словарями значение "не на самом деле", "не всерьез".

> 2. Разг. Для вида, для видимости, не всерьёз, в шутку. Он нарочно сказал, а ты и поверил.

(БТС Кузнецова)
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE

Это значение все в общем-то и объясняет.
Что же касается появления такого значения, очень далекого от исходного, чуть ли не диаметрально противоположного ему, то это действительно интересный вопрос. Будет обсуждаться здесь:
[Ещё раз про "понарошку"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453255)

Answer (score -1):

Понарошку – это как. Наречие образа действия.