# Ещё раз про "понарошку"

Tags: этимология, смысл

Рискну задать ещё один вопрос про слово ***понарошку*** (понарошк**е**). В том не затрагиваются важные вопросы насчёт него. Новичок не очень хорошо сформулировал о нём [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453251/), но зато удачно коснулся этой темы.

Вот что я собрал из разных источников (первый [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83), не буду приводить второй, поскольку статья сильно неграмотная):

***Понарошку*** происходит от *по- + нарочно.*
"Нарочно" означает *специально, намеренно.* Это наречие, которое произошло от слова "нарок", что означает *обет, обещание, наставление.* Слово в старину употребляли в контексте заговоров на порчу. Само же слово тоже состоит из приставки и корня: *на+рок,* где *рок* в значении "судьба", обычно несчастливая (злой рок). Соответственно "на рок" - это на судьбу, имеется в виду "наговорить на судьбу".

В итоге всё это очень странно: *по+нарочно* может означать, на мой взгляд, что-то близкое к тому же *нарочно,* но не противоположную вещь. А ведь *понарошку* значит ***не всерьёз, в шутку***, то есть не *"нарочно",* а как раз *"**не** нарочно".*

***Чем же можно объяснить это противоречие?***

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на вопрос, Бегемотус!

Answer (score 2):

> Чем же можно объяснить это противоречие?

Здесь нет явного противоречия, а то, что есть, - легко объяснимо. 
В основе понятия "нарочный" лежит сема "рок" - "судьба", "предрасположенность". Через неё уже появилась "преднамеренность", "нарочитость". Это преднамеренность семантически противопоставляется объективному, неподвластному человеку течению событий. Причем одинаково хорошо работает как для серьезной преднамеренности, та и для шуточной.

Ну и в довершение, хотя тут это и несколько избыточно, упомяну о том, что в русском (и не только) языке употребление слова в противоположном значении вообще не такое уж редкое дело. Особенно характерно это (почему-то) именно для наречий: *чертовски приятно, жутко весело, страшно интересно*. Тут вообще рационального объяснения обычно нет, разве что - само желание "высказаться наоборот". Но наше "понарошку" вполне в духе этого ряда.

====

> Само же слово тоже состоит из приставки и корня: на+рок, где рок в
>   значении "судьба", обычно несчастливая (злой рок). Соответственно "на
>   рок" - это на судьбу, имеется в виду "наговорить на судьбу".

Вот тут я не совсем согласен. Слишком "любительское" понимание. Все верно, "на+рок", только эта приставка (исходно - предлог) сейчас сильно переосмыслилась и слилась в понимании с "надеяться на", положиться  на" (положиться на судьбу), а исходно она означала "наполненный, находящийся под действием" - ср. набожный. Т.е. "нарочный" - буквально означало бы "положившийся на судьбу". Близко, но все-таки не совсем то, что у вас.

=====
Ой, какой пример с помощью Нацкорпуса нашел!

> Как только полиция в двери, вдруг хлоп... свет погас. А окон много, и
>   все окна почему-то распахнуты. Кинулась полиция к механику, а механик
>   кричит, ругается. "Идите, говорит, к черту! У меня и без того беда:
>   кажется, обмотка якоря перегорела".
>   - Так это он нарочно! - с восхищением воскликнул Толька.
>   - А вот поди-ка ты докажи, нарочно или не нарочно, - усмехнулся Владик...

Гайдар, Военная тайна. 
Вот оно, "несерьезное", "невзаправдашнее" значение.

Comment: Спасибо! *...не совсем то, что у вас.* Ну, это всё-таки не у меня — это было чем-то типа маленького реферата. Процитировал выборочно из второго источника, немножко подправив при этом.

Comment: Ок, у вас в реферате )))

Comment: Да, отличный пример!)

Comment: Кстати, почему *полиция,* а не *милиция?*

Comment: *Особенно характерно это (почему-то) именно для наречий: чертовски приятно, жутко весело, страшно интересно.* В английском то же самое: *awfully, terribly, frightfully* и др. означают *страшно, ужасно* в смысле *очень* (с чем-то положительным).

Comment: *Кстати, почему полиция, а не милиция?*  - )))) Милиция у Гайдара вполне себе добрая и правильная. А это про Львов, тогда еще польский.